# MS EXCEL: Convert (Height) Decimal Feet & Inches to Inches Only

Tags: excel, converters, formula

Using MS Excel (2010), I would like a formula (Not VBA/Macros) that will convert Decimal Feet, Inches and Fraction of a person's height to Only inches.

Example: John is 6' 1 1/4" tall, I have converted the Total height to decimals = 73.250, and would like to convert the Decimal output to only inches, including fraction of height = 73 1/4"

See Sample for your assistance:

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. What is your input? And what is your expected output?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your decimal in inches is in A1, you can use the following to convert to 'tape measure' values.  It's messy but it works:

```
=IF(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)=0,INT(A1),IF(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)=16,INT(A1)+1,IF(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/8=INT(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/8),INT(A1)&"  1/2",IF(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/4=INT(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/4),INT(A1)&"  "&INT(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5))/4&"/4",IF(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/2=INT(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)/2),INT(A1)&"  "&INT(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5))/2&"/8",INT(A1)&"  "&(INT((A1-INT(A1))*16+0.5)&"/16"))))))
```

Answer (score 2):

A formula that would work is

```
=INT(A2)&" "&TEXT((A2-INT(A2)),"# #/#")&CHAR(34)
```

Breaking down the formula:

- **INT(A2)** rounds the number down to the lowest integer
- **&" "&** joins the results of the two formulas with a space
- **A2-INT(A2)** returns the fractional part of the decimal number
- **TEXT(0.125,"# #/#)** sets the formatting of the fraction
- **Char(34)** adds the quotation mark " to the end

Comment: Thank you so much Robert for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated, as I had spent a great deal of time attempting, to what you have done in matter of minutes... again thank you...

Comment: (This isn't *directly* related but I'm going to sneak it in as a comment) If height in feet is stored as a decimal (ie., 5.5) use custom formatting `#'" "#/12` to display **`5' 6/12`**.  If startingwith centimeters in `A1` to ft/in with formula `=(INT(A1/30.48) + ROUND(MOD(a1,30.48)/254,2))*100` (to store as `506`) and use custom format `0"ft "00"in"` (to display as **`5ft 06in`**)

Answer (score 0):

Taken from: http://www.excelforum.com/l/671155-convert-fractions-to-decimals-and-decimal-to-fraction.html

You can append the following to your formula for dec. conversion using `&` :

```
& IF(MROUND(MOD(A1,1),1/16),TEXT(MROUND(MOD(A1,1),1/16)," ?/#?"),"")&""""
```

With this formula: A1 = 73.25, B1 = 1/4"

Answer (score 0):

I know that if I enter =3/4 in a cell it will give me .75 but is there is a formula to convert fractions into decimals or is this the best way to do it? I was also wondering if there is some way to convert the decimal amount to a fraction
for measurement conversions, I know that=B3*25.4 will convert a decimal to mm and so will the formula =CONVERT(E4," in", "mm")
and to convert mm to a decimal a few formulae that work are

```
=CONVERT(H3,"mm","in")
=MROUND(H4/25.4, 1/8)
=H5/25.4
=INT(H6/25.39999918*8)/8
```